# img auto width height and max-height

Tags: html, css

I have this code Here:

```
<table class="media imgTable" border="1" width="auto" height="auto" style=""><tbody>
<tr><td class="xClick" width="auto" height="auto" align="left" valign="center">

<div class="xClick" style="position: relative; left: -1px; top: 3px; width: 200px; padding: 0px 1%; border: 1px solid silver; border-bottom: none; background-color: #ADD8E6;"><?php echo $label; ?></div>

</td></tr>
<tr><td class="xClick" width="auto" height="auto" align="center" valign="center" style="position: relative;">

<img id="img" src="<?php echo $src; ?>" style="width: auto; height: auto;" />

</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

[and it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awuah.png)

It is perfect. Just what I want. but some images are too large and overflow the screen (viewport)

so I tried this:

```
<table border="1" width="auto" height="90%" style=""><tbody>
    <tr><td class="xClick" width="100%" height="" align="left" valign="center">

    <div class="xClick" style="position: relative; left: -1px; top: 3px; width: 200px; padding: 0px 1%; border: 1px solid silver; border-bottom: none; background-color: #ADD8E6;"><?php echo $label; ?></div>

    </td></tr>
    <tr><td class="xClick" width="100%" height="100%" align="center" valign="center" style="position: relative;">

    <img id="img" src="<?php echo $src; ?>" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: auto; height: auto; max-height: 100%;" />

    </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5jSB.png)

I want to make the img have auto width and height and max height. So the image is completely wrapped by the td just like in the first picture. Even for images that are large and overflow the viewport/screen;

Answer (score 0):

Is this not sufficient?

```
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Comment: the problem is that I need to have position absolute on the img and height and width and position relative for the containing td but the effects are not desirable.